Telegram cached url preview show incorrect url – how can I fix it?
I'm encountering an issue with Telegram's link preview caching. When I try to open this link in Telegram:
https://www.tethermaker.com/signup?ref=url
Telegram changes the URL to:
https://www.tethermaker.com/signup?ref=wemaketether123
and shows the wrong link preview. It appears Telegram may be caching the metadata and/or URL
We tried updating the cached information via Webpage Bot, but this only changed all URLs to be sent to that URL. I mean, I can change it to ?ref=abc, but if I go to another ?ref=xyz, it still goes to abc.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!


We can't answer this, based on fake example URLs. Are you setting og:url and/or canonical correctly?

you can try this url : https://www.tethermaker.com/signup?ref=url
I am using reactjs just as SPA, also I added og:url and canonical by using react-helmet-async

Most of these social networking sites do not interpret any such meta tags, when you try to set them using client-side JavaScript - they only interpret the initial HTML code your server returned, when the URL was requested. I would assume, for Telegram it is likely they same.

When neither og:url  nor a canonical link are specified, it should use the original URL as-is; but I couldn't tell you if Telegram figures they should handle this differently for some reason. But explicitly supplying the desired URL, is your best bet to gets this working as desired everywhere. You would need some sort of pre-render solution for that, so that the initial HTML code your system returns already contains it.
